# h:messages gives no output

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I'm learning about bean validation. I have created simple form with username and password input fields which are bound through backing bean to model (User) properties username and password. I have marked them with annotation:

```
@Id
@NotNull(message="Username cannot be empty")
private String username;
@NotNull(message="Password cannot be empty")
private String password;
```

Now on the page with that form I've put `<h:messages/>` inside `<h:form>...</h:form>`. I submit empty form, I am redirected to the same page (I have return null in action method in backing bean) but no messages are being displayed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is instead of using `@NotNull`, use `@Size` because empty input field is actually empty string and not `null`.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get `@NotNull` to work, you indeed need to let JSF set empty strings as `null`. In JSF 2.0 you can do that by adding the following context param to the `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I can't tell from experience if that would trigger the `@NotNull`, but in theory it should. Give it a try.